Connection with constant Christoffel symbols
Assume that $(\mathcal{M},\nabla)$ is a manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with an affine connection $\nabla$. Assume that there is a chart in which the Christoffel symboles, defined as
$$
\nabla_{e_j}e_j = \sum_k \Gamma^k_{i,j} e_k,
$$
are constant on $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $e_i$ are the coordinate vector fields. Note that I don't mean that at $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, the $\Gamma^k_{i,j}$ are independent of i,j and k.
Can we say something particular about $(\mathcal{M},\nabla)$ ? For instance, is there a chance to have explicite geodesics ?
Thank you for you help.

I don't think it gives much information about the global manifold structure, let alone its geodesics. However, there's always a change of coordinates which turns $\Gamma_{i,j}^{k}$ into zero (a composition of an exponential map and isomorphism $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow T_{p}M$) at a single point $p$ which locally defines a geodesic. However the neighbourhood in which it holds is to be determined.

@TedShifrin, I've been waiting for you to appear in one of these questions. :)
Does it always impy flatness, though? I thought flatness follows if all $\Gamma_{i, j}^{k}$ are zero for any point on the manifold. Otheriwise, it feels like I can, using the definition of Crystoffel symbols, find some $g_{ij}$'s which could be linear in coordinates.

@EgorLarionov Yeah, I'm afraid I spoke too quickly. I'm going to have to withdraw that claim and think some more.
